# Convert float to decimal, why need explicit conversion?

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal

i have known the decimal type is more preciser than float, so i think it should be reasonable that converting float to decimal will like converting float to double. But in realty, it doesn't true.

```js
float a = 1.1f;
double d = a;

decimal c = (decimal)d; // true
decimal e = (decimal)a; // true

decimal f = a; // error
```

Comment: Please review the guidelines for posting on this site. You should not place tags (e.g. `[C#]`) in your question title as the site already has a suitable tagging system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A `float` has the approximate range ±1.5 x 10<sup>−45</sup> to ±3.4 x 10<sup>38</sup>
  and a precision of 6-9 digits.
- A `decimal` has the approximate range ±1.0 x 10<sup>-28</sup> to ±7.9228 x 10<sup>28</sup> and a precision of 28-29 digits.

It would cause an exception to assign a `float` to a `decimal` if the `float` is outside the decimal's range.

Therefore you get a compile error if you try to do that without casting. C# errs on the side of caution in these cases.

Here we can see the difference between *range* and *precision*.

A `float` has greater *range* than a `decimal` and a `decimal` has greater *precision* than a `float`.

(Note that you also get a compile error if you try to assign a `decimal` to a `float` without casting, but this time because it might lose data rather than because it would throw an exception.)

Comment: It (trying to convert out of range float to decimal) actually causes not a data loss but an exception.